# scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve surprising behaviour for large sparse matrices on Linux systems

Tags: python, linux, windows, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am computing the solution of a linear system Ax=b with A a large (typically 200,000 lines and columns for the associated dense matrix) sparse matrix and b a sparse matrix of about 100 columns.

When I run my code on Windows systems (Python **2.7**, scipy **0.14.0**), the following command

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
...
Temp = spsolve(A.tocsc(),b.tocsc())
```

runs smoothly and requires about 7 GB of ram memory.

Running the *exact same code* with the *exact same matrices* on Linux systems (same CPU, same amount of RAM memory: 64 GB, Linux Mint **17.3**, python **2.7**, scipy **0.13.3**) requires more than 20 GB of ram memory and it crashes with the following error message:

`<function umfpack_di_numeric at ...> failed with UMFPACK_ERROR_out_of_memory`    (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezdPi.png))

Because this error is os dependent, I ruled out any issue regarding the matrices **A** and **b** (contrary to some of the mentioned solutions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333689/scipy-sparse-invert-or-spsolve-lead-to-umfpack-error-out-of-memory)), and I am trying to find a fix specific to Linux... But I do not know where to start... Does anyone would have any idea of what is going on ? And why would such a problem be specific to Linux systems ?

Please find below the full error message:

`Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "...", line 1533, in mmvConstruction
    ...
  File "...", line 1555, in modes_cb
    Temp = spsolve(k[inter][:,inter].tocsc(),k[inter][:,exter].tocsc())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 151, in spsolve
    Afactsolve = factorized(A)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 352, in factorized
    umf.numeric(A)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/umfpack/umfpack.py", line 450, in numeric
    umfStatus[status]))
RuntimeError:<function umfpack_di_numeric at ...> failed with UMFPACK_ERROR_out_of_memory`

[image: error message]

**Update**: still trying to find out a solution... it seems that the latest version of BLAS on Linux Mint is quite old: 1.8.2. On Windows, I use BLAS 1.9.1. When using the `test_numpy.py` file available here: https://gist.github.com/osdf/3842524#file-test_numpy-py I notice very significant differences between Linux and Windows: **Linux** : version 1.8.2, maxint 9223372036854775807, dot: 0.76 s - **Windows** : version 1.9.1, maxint 2147483647, dot: 0,037 s. I am investigating if OPENBLAS on Linux could be a solution to this problem...

**Update 2:** I realized that the problem may be hardware related. Indeed, an older PC, with the exact same libraries on the same Linux Mint distribution (Rosa 17.3) provides much more satisfying results. The benchmark mentioned in the first update gives on this old PC: **Linux** : version 1.8.2, maxint 9223372036854775807, dot: 0,054 s.

Comment: What BLAS did you compile against when you installed numpy/scipy on the Linux system? I suspect this is the problem...

Comment: the screen shot is illegible and unsearchable. Please copy/paste screen output into Q and use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box to keep proper formatting. Good luck.

Comment: @Will I used the following BLAS library on my Linux Mint system: `apt-get install liblapack-dev`. Regarding scipy, I installed simply `apt-get install python-scipy` without any firther recompilation.

Comment: @shellter the screen shot is indeed unsearchable but I put the key part of the error message in the post: `<function umfpack_di_numeric at ...> failed with UMFPACK_ERROR_out_of_memory` the rest is, I believe, less relevant.

Comment: As you have included the relevant error message, good show. But please don't get in the habit of posting screen shots. They make it difficult for pros to search for phrases they expect, and to copy/paste code to test in their local environment AND they are a nuisance to read. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: From the error message (which you really should copy-paste, sorry for raising the issue again), `Tkinter` seems to be involved and you apparently use a GUI. Could you specify what you are doing exactly and try to run the code without the GUI?

Comment: @Silmathoron so I am using a TKinter graphic interface but the code is executed outside of Tkinter, I tried to run the code without TKinter but it did not change the fact that it crashes (same error message)...

Comment: Innards of sparse matrices have been reworked after scipy 0.13 --- this might (or might not) have gotten better in more recent scipy versions.

Comment: still trying to find out a solution... it seems that the latest version of BLAS on Linux Mint is quite old: 1.8.2. On Windows, I use BLAS 1.9.1. When using the `test_numpy.py` file available here: https://gist.github.com/osdf/3842524#file-test_numpy-py I notice very significant differences between Linux and Windows: **Linux** : version 1.8.2, maxint 9223372036854775807, dot: 0.76 s - **Windows** : version 1.9.1, maxint 2147483647, dot: 0,037 s. I am investigating if OPENBLAS on Linux could be a solution to this problem...

Comment: This is something you may want to post on the scipy mailing list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the tip, I just did. If I get any answer, I will post it here.

Comment: @Alain Did you get any answer from the scipy mailing list? I am facing exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Well, after thorough investigations, I am now convinced that the issue I had is related to the fact that **Linux Mint (Rosa 17.3)** may not be optimized for the most recent processors.

The comparisons I mentioned in the updates of my post underlined that the software installation was correct. I then installed **Fedora 23** on my PC, installing sequentially:

- libblas
- python
- python-scipy

Then I ran the exact same code with the exact same matrices and there was no issue whatsoever: RAM consumption was limited to about 7 GB, similarly to what was observed on Windows systems.